# onTouchListener not working after layout change

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, ontouchlistener

I want to get feedback when the user swipes anywhere on the screen. I found some code that does that using an onTouchListener. And it worked.
Today I did some rework on my UI setup and added a lot of new layouts to organize it a little nicer. But my onTouch event is never triggering any more!

My guess is that some of the layouts might be overlapping and stealing the event. But I have not been successful trying to use the following arguments in the xml.

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
android:visibility="invisible"
```

This is the code running in onCreate:

```
View window = getWindow().getDecorView();
window.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("YEY! A TOUCH EVENT!");
        return true;
    }
});

RelativeLayout tab1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layTab1);
tab1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("YEY! A TOUCH EVENT!");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Any ideas as for what might have changed when adding new layouts is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was after much troubleshooting.
My layout hierchy was the following:

```
- activity_main (RelativeLayout)
--- layTab1 (RelativeLayout)
----- (ScrollView)
------- layTab1View (LinearLayout)
--------- (STUFF FOR THIS TAB)
--- layTab2 (RelativeLayout)
----- (ScrollView)
------- layTab2View (LinearLayout)
--------- (STUFF FOR THIS TAB)
```

And I was trying to grab events from the `activity_main` layout. Which was working fine til I added a `ScrollView`. Apparently, the `ScrollView` consumes all the touch events. To work around this problem. I had to add a listener to all of the `LinearLayout` children of the `ScrollView` since only one tab will be active at the time.

I do how ever feel that having multiple different elements listen for the same event to trigger a menu popup is slightly unnessesary? So if at all possibly I would love to hear suggestions as for how I could solve this more "cleanly".

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Creating your layout design with `frame layout` 
Like Below:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>

//Your Layout design

</FrameLayout>
```

And make view_main .setOnTouchListner in code.. Other layout desing now can't steal touchlistner event from this way..

```
findViewById(R.id.view_main).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("YEY! A TOUCH EVENT!");
        return true;
    }
});
```

I hope this can help you.let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did how ever not get around to trying it before I managed to find some information about the ScrollView. So I don't know if it would work or not. But given what I discovered about ScrollViews, I do find it unlikely.